# javascript pagination with foreach loop data

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have several questions with answers, I get the data by for each loop in Laravel blade and I want to show question per page with next and previous button to go to next question
any idea how to implement this with java script?
thank you

Comment: Please post some examples of the code you are using, and detail what methods you have attempted to solve your problem. With these details, the community will be much more able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer and it works fine but I don't know how to implement it if the data are coming from for each loop in Lavravel blade

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        //Pagination JS
        //how much items per page to show
        var show_per_page = 2;
        //getting the amount of elements inside pagingBox div
        var number_of_items = $('#pagingBox').children().size();
        //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
        var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items / show_per_page);

        //set the value of our hidden input fields
        $('#current_page').val(0);
        $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

        //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

        /* 
        what are we going to have in the navigation?
            - link to previous page
            - links to specific pages
            - link to next page
        */
        var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
        var current_link = 0;
        while (number_of_pages > current_link) {
            navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link + ')" longdesc="' + current_link + '">' + (current_link + 1) + '</a>';
            current_link++;
        }
        navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

        $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

        //add active_page class to the first page link
        $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

        //hide all the elements inside pagingBox div
        $('#pagingBox').children().css('display', 'none');

        //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
        $('#pagingBox').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

    });



    //Pagination JS

    function previous() {

        new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
        //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
        if ($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length == true) {
            go_to_page(new_page);
        }

    }

    function next() {
        new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
        //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
        if ($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length == true) {
            go_to_page(new_page);
        }

    }

    function go_to_page(page_num) {
        //get the number of items shown per page
        var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

        //get the element number where to start the slice from
        start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

        //get the element number where to end the slice
        end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

        //hide all children elements of pagingBox div, get specific items and show them
        $('#pagingBox').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

        /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
        and remove that class from previously active page link*/
        $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num + ']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

        //update the current page input field
        $('#current_page').val(page_num);
    }
```

```css
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .text-info {
        color: #31708f;
    }
    
    .physicianList ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .physicianList ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 240px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .physicianBox {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        color: #333;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    
    .physicianBox .physicianPic {
        padding: 15px 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .physicianBox .physicianPic img {
        border: 6px solid #f8f8f8;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 120px;
        width: 120px;
    }
    
    .physicianInfo {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .physicianInfo h6 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .physicianBox strong {
        color: #444;
    }
    
    .physicianBox p {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 22px;
    }
    
    .physicianBio {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 3px;
    }
    
    .physicianModal {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .physicianModal .physicianPic img {
        border: 6px solid #f8f8f8;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 180px;
        width: 180px;
    }
    
    .physicianModal .info p,
    .physicianModal .info .text-info {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .showBioBtn {
        background-color: #337ab7;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    /*Pagination CSS*/
    
    #page_navigation {
        clear: both;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    
    #page_navigation a {
        padding: 3px 6px;
        border: 1px solid #2e6da4;
        margin: 2px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    
    .active_page {
        background: #337ab7;
        color: white !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="physicianList">
    <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
    <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />
    <ul id="pagingBox">
        <li>
            <div class="physicianBox">
                <div class="physicianPic">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gE7cc5/user_4.jpg" alt="user_4" border="0">
                </div>

                <div class="physicianInfo">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h6><strong>Emily</strong></h6>
                        <p class="text-info">Web Designer</p>
                        <p>+880-168-240</p>
                        <p>emily@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="physicianBio">
                    <a class="showBioBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Show BIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="physicianBox">
                <div class="physicianPic">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/czhXAQ/user_1.jpg" alt="user_1" border="0">
                </div>

                <div class="physicianInfo">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h6><strong>Abram</strong></h6>
                        <p class="text-info">Frontend Developer</p>
                        <p>+880-168-240</p>
                        <p>abram@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="physicianBio">
                    <a class="showBioBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Show BIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="physicianBox">
                <div class="physicianPic">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gE7cc5/user_4.jpg" alt="user_4" border="0">
                </div>

                <div class="physicianInfo">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h6><strong>Emily 2</strong></h6>
                        <p class="text-info">Web Designer</p>
                        <p>+880-168-240</p>
                        <p>emily@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="physicianBio">
                    <a class="showBioBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Show BIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="physicianBox">
                <div class="physicianPic">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/czhXAQ/user_1.jpg" alt="user_1" border="0">
                </div>

                <div class="physicianInfo">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h6><strong>Abram 2</strong></h6>
                        <p class="text-info">Frontend Developer</p>
                        <p>+880-168-240</p>
                        <p>abram@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="physicianBio">
                    <a class="showBioBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Show BIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="physicianBox">
                <div class="physicianPic">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hnYLh5/team_member01.jpg" alt="team_member01" border="0">
                </div>

                <div class="physicianInfo">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h6><strong>Emily 3</strong></h6>
                        <p class="text-info">Web Designer</p>
                        <p>+880-168-240</p>
                        <p>emily@gmail.com</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="physicianBio">
                    <a class="showBioBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Show BIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```